# Paypal nvp api - Post request not working

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, paypal, paypal-ipn

I've been reading through the API and looking at samples and they seem to use POST to send their request. When I tried using POST I kept getting back a 10001 error. When I switched the request method to GET it works.

I was using the following code for Posting the request - FAILS

```
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        req.Method = "Post";
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        WebResponse response = req.GetResponse();
```

I use the exact same code for using GET, except for method type - WORKS

```
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        req.Method = "Get";
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        WebResponse response = req.GetResponse();
```

Can I use GET for making API requests? The reason I ask is because every single example on the net uses POST, and it is used in their API examples as well. Is there some sort of security risk of using GET even though it is sent to an ssl link?

Lastly, why is the POST request sending back an invalid response?

Comment: Are you using their sandbox to test with?

Comment: yes this is using the sandbox

Comment: @chobo I'm also having problems creating manual posts to the NVP interface without using the paypal_base.dll. Were you ever able to figure this out? I would love to see a bit more source code from a working solution if available.